# Overwrite a class extended many times

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

When I have to override a method of a class that is used as extends in many modules I have to copy the class path and put it under app 
`/local/Mage/.../Core_Class_Extended_ManyTimes.php`.

But there is no way to pull me inside the parent class and extend it in turn so as to override a single method even if there are no namespaces? so as to be slightly safer in case of updates of the core?

es: `app/local/Mage/.../Core_Class_Extended_ManyTimes.php`:

```
class Core_Class_Extended_ManyTimes extends SOMETHINGS_ORIGINAL_Core_Class_Extended_ManyTimes
```